# Search for a Atom in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have most Compound Term, such as:

```
likes(a, b).
likes(c, b).
likes(a, d).
likes(b, c).
likes(c, a).
likes(a, f).
go(a, t).
go(t, d).
go(g, a).
go(f, g).
go(f, a).
```

I want to search Compound Tern, value of Atom is "a", value of the other Atom is any value.

The result of Prolog return:

```
likes(a, b).
likes(a, d).
likes(c, a).
likes(a, f).
go(a, t).
go(g, a).
go(f, a).
```

Please, help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to "reify" the predicate term. Your theory becomes:

```
do(likes, a, b).
do(likes, c, b).
do(likes, a, d).
do(likes, b, c).
do(likes, c, a).
do(likes, a, f).
do(go, a, t).
do(go, t, d).
do(go, g, a).
do(go, f, g).
do(go, f, a).
```

Add the following:

```
has_value(X) :- do(_, X, _)
has_value(X) :- do(_, _, X)
```

And you're done.

You could use meta-predicates like =.. to avoid changing your theory. Personally I think that's the wrong approach. Better to have the right formalisation of the problem from the start.

Comment: thank @NotAUser. I think that your answer is also correct. Do you have another manner?

Comment: Have a look at CapelliC's answer if you want to go for meta-predicated and compatibility with the current theory. I think these two are pretty much the only two ways to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've written here a generic helper. I thought that less builtins were needed...

```
search_facts_by_arg(Functor, Arg, C) :-
    current_functor(Functor, Arity),
    Arity >= 2, % because of 'value of the other Atom is any value.'
    length(Args, Arity),
    C =.. [Functor|Args],
    clause(C, true),
    once((arg(_, C, A), A == Arg)).
```

- [current_functor](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_functor/2)(Functor, Arity)
- Arity [>=](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3E=%29/2) 2
- [length](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2)(Args, Arity)
- C [=..](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2) [Functor|Args]
- [clause](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clause/2)(C, true)
- [once](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=once/1)(Callable)
- [arg](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3)(_, C, A)
- A [==](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28==%29/2) Arg

Phew...

test:

```
?- search_facts_by_arg(go, a, C).
C = go(a, t) ;
C = go(g, a) ;
C = go(f, a) ;
false.
```

*edit*: after @false' suggestion, the code could be simplified

```
search_facts_by_arg(Functor, Arg, C) :-
    functor(C, Functor, 2),
    clause(C, true),
    once((arg(_, C, A), A == Arg)).
```

here is the [functor](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=functor/3)/3 documentation. The essential builtin is clause/2, here another simplified way, using univ to build the 'template' head:

```
search_facts_by_arg(Functor, Arg, C) :-
    C =.. [Functor,_,_],
    clause(C, true),
    once((arg(_, C, A), A == Arg)).
```

Comment: This is the first time that I see `current_functor/2`. Does not `functor(Functor,_,Arity)` suffice? `current_functor/2` is extremely SWI specific.

Comment: Thank @CapelliC. I think that your answer is also correct. But, I also want to use only value of "a" to search the fact. This is a function: 
`search_facts_by_arg(Arg, C)` 
Arg is "a".
C is the result:

likes(a, b).
likes(a, d).
likes(c, a).
likes(a, f).
go(a, t).
go(g, a).
go(f, a).