# Finding all predicates with the same arity

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

Is it possible to pose a query such as

```
?- X(C).
```

that can return all the predicates that have arity 1? In general, is it possible to refer to a predicate name by using a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`current_predicate(X/1).` shows predicates with arity 1.

You can use `call` to call a goal from a variable.

Comment: As pointed out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494146/search-for-a-atom-in-prolog), `current_predicate` is SWI-specific. Is there a more general way?

Comment: In the linked question user false says that `current_functor/2` is SWI-specific, not `current_predicate/1`. I think `current_predicate/1` is in ISO. I checked in 5 Prolog systems I have installed, and all of them have `current_predicate/1`.

Comment: @Dan: Sergii is right. For some time, I try to add [this link](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#status_quo) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10914371/772868) to [the tag description of ISO Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/iso-prolog/info) but I have no luck: t is rejected all the time...